# Using Microsoft Translator API in Android application

Tags: android, localization, language-translation, microsoft-translator

I have created sample Android application which translates text using Microsoft Translator API.
I included jar file from this project https://github.com/boatmeme/microsoft-translator-android-test. Here is my application code...

```
public class translateSample extends Activity{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Translate.setClientId("my client key");
        Translate.setClientSecret("client secret key");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_translate);
        Button Trans1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.translate);
        Trans1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {

                EditText Input = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.input);
                EditText Output = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.output);
                        String In =Input.getText().toString();
                        //String Out;
                        try
                        {
                            String Out = Translate.execute(In, Language.ENGLISH, Language.FRENCH);

                            Input.setText(Out);
                            Output.setText(Out);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

I am getting following error:

```
java.lang.Exception: [microsoft-translator-api] Error retrieving translation : Hostname <datamarket.accesscontrol.windows.net> was not verified
```

Please help me to solve this error.

Comment: It seems some authorization issue, see this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh454950.aspx.

Comment: i have gone through the link..but the example application is developed in ASP.NET and i am building application in android. I have referred an example from https://github.com/boatmeme/microsoft-translator-android-test which is not using Access Token.

Answer (score 2):

You need to turn on the WI-Fi on your device in order for your application to work. I had the same error turn on WI-FI and everything was working smooth.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you enter your client and secret keys in the respective places in the following code:

```
    Translate.setClientId("my client key");
    Translate.setClientSecret("client secret key");
```

Answer (score 0):

first you must make ID and password in bing and write them in your code like below 
Translate.setClientId("my client key");
    Translate.setClientSecret("client secret key");
take care the net must be exist because this dictionary work on line

Comment: I don't hink the OP has forgotten to create an account, but just did not write his account in here (at least thats what i hope)

Answer (score 0):

It seems the JAVA code that Jonathan Briggs Wrote does not work on ACCESS TOKENS with accounts created after 2012 . It says that in the file. Check out README.md file